# Proper android up navigation with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm wokring on an application that's got the classic list-content pattern, showing a list of menu choices on the left hand side and the content in the center. The different menu choices will swap the content with a corresponding fragment displaying new information.

I'm struggling with implementing proper up navigation:

```
|---------------------------------------|
|< Frag. B |                B1  B2  B3  |
|----------|----------------------------|
|Fragment A|                            |
[Fragment B]                            |
|Fragment C|        Fragment B.2        |
|Fragment D|                            |
|Fragment E|                            |
|----------|----------------------------|
```

In the above illustration the user have navigated to Fragment B.2. He first selected Fragment B from the menu, afterwards he pressed a button which took him "further into" Fragment B, to Fragment B.2.

If the user now presses press the HOME (as in home as up) button he will return to Fragment B. This is working as intented.

However, inside Fragment B.2 there is a button in the ActionBar that takes the user to Fragment E.2:

```
|---------------------------------------|
|< Frag. E |                E1  E2  E3  |
|----------|----------------------------|
|Fragment A|                            |
|Fragment B|                            |
|Fragment C|        Fragment E.2        |
|Fragment D|                            |
[Fragment E]                            |
|----------|----------------------------|
```

When the user arrives here in Fragment E.2, the previous fragment in the back stack is Fragment B.2. My current implementation is simply calling `getActivity().onBackPressed()` when the HOME button is pressed and the user will simply return to Fragment B.2.
This does not make sense to the user so I would like to implement a system that will take the user to Fragment E now (even though Fragment B.2 is the previous fragment in the back stack).

My immediate idea was to have a reference to the fragment that should behave as the previous fragment in the back stack, inside every fragment. 
Fragment B.2 would have a reference to Fragment B, Fragment E.2 would have a reference to Fragment E, etc. When the HOME button got pressed
I would launch the fragment that is referenced as the previous fragment. I debated this solution but quickly realized this might become pretty
complicated in regards to the back stack, not to mention that it sounds very clumsy.

Is there a smart way to implement this kind of behavior?

Comment: If he presses the HOME button with the current implementation (getActivity().onBackPressed()),  What does that mean? BackPressed is different from home..

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have updated the post with clarification on what I mean.. my current implementation is manually calling the onBackPressed() method when the home button is pressed, which leads to unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: your design is wrong
Simulating a back press on the home key is just crazy, and taking the user to a screen he never went to is just crazy!

Long answer: if you want to achieve such a madness: as you cannot insert a fragment in the back stack, I would open fragment E on the ActionBar item selected, and then launch automatically Fragment E.2?

Other solution: You could also launch fragment E from the onPause() of Fragment E.2 if fragment E.2 opened from ActionBar.

Comment: I am aware that the implementation simulating back press is insufficient and it's something I put in as a temporary solution. I am very interested in tips on how to better implement the home button functionality. As far as I can tell it's supposed to take the user "up one level" from his current position. How can I specify the  different levels in my app and then let the home button work like this? Thanks again for your input.

Comment: What about the 2 ideas I proposed?

Comment: Sorry, my prev comment was submitted too soon by mistake. Have now made some edits. Rather than implementing workarounds for "madness" I'd like to make some adjustments and achieve better design :-)

Comment: Better design is => User go to the screen he left when pressed home. Period. Using an other activity/fragment will always be a workaround.

Comment: The smart way to to this is to replace fragment E.2 by Fragment E in the onPause().